# How to arrange cards on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

I'm currently developing an app that uses cards. I saw the usage of cards in the official Google app.

However, the Google app differs a bit on mobiles and tablets.

On mobiles it shows the cards under - each other without much space next to them. (It also does that on my phone in landscape mode)

On tablets it puts two cards next to each other. (sometimes one big and two small, sometimes two equal sized)

Can someone here explain me how they do that and what kind of XML or Java I need to add, to put a similar functionality into my app. (I currently have working cards in my app, but they have the width set to fill_parent so they fill the entire screen)

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and different [`LayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) to achieve that.

An example of code would be something like:

```
// during onCreate
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
LayoutManager lm;
if(isPhone) {
   if(isLandscape) {
      lm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
   } else {
      lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
   }
} else {
   if(isLandscape) {
      lm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
   } else {
      lm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
   }
}
rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
rv.setAdapter(... your adapter with the cards...);
```

To achieve different spacing in-between items you can use a [`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html). And if you need headers, footers, or other utilities I suggest you to check out my library [RecyclerViewTools on GitHub](https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools)

Comment: Looks like this is what I'm looking for. If I won't get any better explanation by tomorrow (it's 11:15PM over here and I'll take some sleep now), I'll pick yours as the correct answer. Thanks for the code. This is awesome work! :)

Comment: Forgot to mention. To make different spacing in-between cards, you can use a https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html
if your Recycler is growing complex, make sure to check my library which have a bunch of utilities for it: https://github.com/eyeem/RecyclerViewTools

Comment: okay. this exceeds what i'm needing :) I hope I'll manage to get that two cards in a row thing done tomorrow. with your references. If there are some youtube tutorials about RecyclerView then it won't be a big problem. Otherwhise I'll read that entire doc until it works.

Comment: just Google it.. there're LOADS of tutorials about it. Gute Nacht!

Answer (score 0):

They define a separate layout file for larger devices in a directory like `res/layout-large/my_layout.xml`. Android will automatically select the appropriate layout for the device. For more info check out these links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: okay. thx that makes me understand how it works with XM. But what when I want to generate those layouts? Any idea? :)

Comment: Well one way is to have your code check for a layout element you only included in your tablet layout. If it exists/isn't null then use your tablet optimized code.

Answer (score 0):

Android allows for use of different layout xml files for different screen configurations based on the resource folder you use.

for instance a layout resource folder named layout-sw400dp will show on screens at lease 400dp wide

Read up on it [on the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

Comment: okay. thx that makes me understand how it works with XM. But what when I want to generate those layouts? Any idea? :)

Comment: Have you read the documentation (not just that page that I linked, but on developing for android in general)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2S68gOtHjoXOW5tRGRYMTdHazA/view?usp=sharing That one. I read all the guide lines about cards today and I think I also read all documentations about cards.